# How to give url-pattern in servlet filter, if using AngularJS routing?

Tags: html, angularjs, servlet-filters

***Scenario*** : There is a web-application which is using AngularJS UI-routing. 
***what is done*** : First time session is created in a servlet filter named ***FirstPageFilter.java***.

```
@WebFilter(filterName="FirstPageFilter",urlPatterns="/*")
public class FirstPageFilter implements Filter{

@Override
public void destroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest)request;
    HttpSession session = httpRequest.getSession(true);
    FNBaseSessionObject sessionObject = (FNBaseSessionObject)session.getAttribute("sessionObject");
    if (sessionObject != null ) {
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        return;
    }
    /*else{
        System.out.println("Not going anywhere.....");
    }*/
}

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
    /*System.out.println("filter initialized");*/
}

}
```

Right now it is applied on all the pages.But i want to apply it only on home-page.html.

***index.html***

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="container">
        <div ui-view></div>
        <div ng-include="'footer.html'"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have done ui-routing on index.html. By default home-page will be shown.Which i have provided in routing.js

***routing.js***

```
 ribWeb.config(['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider',
               function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home-page');

$stateProvider.state('home-page', {
    url: '/home-page',
    templateUrl: 'home-page.html'
});
```

***What i am trying to do*** : I am trying to manage sessions in this scenario. First time when home-page.html is hit,session will be created and on other pages that session will be get.If session is invalidate after specific time, then home-page.html page must be returned.

I am confused how to provide urlPattern for home-page.html . i have tried using /home-page and /home-page.html 
But in both the cases filter is initialized, but doFilter is not called.

Is there something i am doing wrong? What Url-pattern should i provide?

Answer (score 1):

Angular's paths are on the hash/fragment part of the URL (i.e. after the `#` part). These are purely client side and never reach the server, which means you can't use those server filters to track moves between `ui-router` states.

What is usually done is setting up your server so that requests that should have a session return 401 status code when there is no session and on your client side you provide an [interceptor](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http) that handles generally all of those errors by routing the app to the appropriate page (usually, the login page).

Comment: i Want to manage session only on client side. Is this possible? As i am also not getting 401 status

Comment: Well managing session only on the client without getting updates from the server isn't really possible, since sessions are held on the server (unless sessions are represented by some cookie that the server sets with an expiry date or something like that). In any way, I believe the right choice in most cases is as I described (letting the server check whether you're in session for every request)

Comment: oh sorry.. i mean server side.

Comment: Then yes, you can. How you do that depends on your server-side framework and how you manage your sessions.